# Google Campaign & Analytics URLs with .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, google-analytics

One of our clients is launching a campaign around our city and one of the requirements they want is to track from what item a visitor has scanned in a QR code. To achieve this I have entered this into my .htaccess file:

```
RewriteRule ^(beermat|poster|flyer)$ /video?utm_source=$1&utm_medium=PrintedMaterial&utm_campaign=VideoCampaign2012 [R=301]
```

So if anyone scans in the QR code that has the address: http://www.website.com/beermat it redirects to /video with the relevant attributes.

If I have the google analytics code on the /video page this should work, correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this plugin to see if google-analytics is recording anything.
This way you can see directly if it is working or not.

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/jnkmfdileelhofjcijamephohjechhna

Answer (score 0):

I think it would be better for you to make "poster" a directory, and the index.php inside it should set $_SESSION['found']="poster" then redirect to the main page which would read from the SESSION.

The added benefit is that you're not left with any ugly GET data, just a nice clean url, but the downside is that you have to manually create the directories, so only do this if you have a manageable amount.

Comment: Lol, that's ok - i am not the best at explaining.